# ChromeDriver don't go to url

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with ChromeDriver v2.9, and Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).
I want open a website, so here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("test-type", "whitelisted-ips=comma-separated-ips", "excludeSwitches", "ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.ToCapabilities();
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory, options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
    }
```

When program run, it's open Chrome but not open the website, and the text in address bar is "data:'".
So what is prolem with me?

Comment: It shows data on top but after that it navigates to Google. There is no issue.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid but it dont show Google Webpage

Comment: It shows, I've tested your code.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid it's dont show in my pc,
because i runmy chrome 64bit?